# Dritte Person Plural im Bezug auf Unternehmen

Tags: grammaticality

Betrachten wir folgende zwei Sätze:

> Google versprach der Welt einen neuen Messenger. Sie stellten ihn aber bereits nach weniger als einem Jahr wieder ein.

Vor einiger Zeit habe ich etwas ähnliches geschrieben, was sofort von zwei Leuten dahingehend kritisiert wurde, dass "Sie stellten" am Anfang des zweiten Satzes im Bezug auf das im ersten Satz genannte Unternehmen falsch sei.

Ich bin es gewohnt, über Unternehmen in der dritten Person Plural zu sprechen. Sie sprechen ja auch in der ersten Person Plural über sich selbst.

Ist das falsch?

Comment: Wäre das wahr, hättest Du im ersten Satz schreiben müssen "Google versprachen der Welt einen neuen Messenger", was Du aber unterlassen hast. Wieso?

Comment: @userunknown Vielleicht ist es ja sowas ähnliches wie beim Geschlecht von "Mädchen", dass man das grammatikalische Geschlecht / die grammatikalische Person wählt, wenn es nah an der Nennung des Subjekts oder Objekts ist, aber etwas später dann das semantische.

Comment: "Die Feuerwehr rückte aus. Erst löschte sie das Wohngebäude, dann wandte sie sich dem Geräteschuppen zu." Wieso sollte man zur Mehrzahl wechseln? "Die Polizei verfolgte die Bankräuber. Sie waren verletzt." Ist da für Dich unklar, wer verletzt war?

Comment: @userunknown Das funktioniert aber nicht immer. Beispiel: "Google versprach den Bewohnern von Finnland einen neuen Messenger. Sie stellten ihn aber bereits nach weniger als einem Jahr wieder ein." Da ist ja auch nicht unklar, wer den Messenger einstellte.

Comment: Ihr macht es mir ziemlich schwer, eine Antwort zu akzeptieren, denn damit, eine der drei Antworten zu akzeptieren, würde ich mir ja selbst die korrekte Antwort aussuchen. Und bisher hat keine der 3 Antworten auch nur einen einzigen Upvote.

Comment: Du kannst die 2 Sätze hintereinanderschreiben, aber der Wechsel von Ein- zu Mehrzahl ist unmotiviert. "... Messenger, stellte ihn aber (...) wieder ein." wäre richtig.

Answer (score 2):

Eine Firma wird üblicherweise im Singular verwendet, solange der Name nicht auf Plural schließen lässt. Das erkennt man schon am ersten Satz deines Beispiels, in dem es richtig heißt:

> Google *versprach* (nicht: <del>versprachen</del>) der Welt einen neuen Messenger.

Im Gegensatz dazu eine Firma, die qua Name im Plural steht:

> Die »Stadtwerke Hintertupflfing« *versprachen* ihren Kunden günstigen Strom und günstiges Wasser.

Wenn nun in einem Folgesatz auf die bereits genannte Firma mit einem Pronomen zurückgegriffen wird, hat sich das Pronomen nach dem Numerus des vorigen Satzes zu richten – so wird es im Deutschen üblicherweise noch gehandhabt. Die Frage stellt sich, ob nun *Google* maskulin, feminin oder neutral ist. Da sich der Name nicht offensichtlich einem Geschlecht oder Genus zuordnen lässt, tendiere ich für *Google* zu *es.*

> **Es** stellte ihn aber bereits nach weniger als einem Jahr wieder ein.

Wieder im Gegensatz dazu ein Pluralname; wir greifen auf die Stadtwerke Hintertupflfing zurück:

> **Sie** erhöhten aber nach zwei Wochen schon die Preise.

Wie schon angedeutet können aber auch andere grammatikalische Geschlechter korrekt sein:

> Der *Stadtbäcker* backt die besten Semmeln. **Er** verlangt aber auch horrende Preise.
>
> Die *Post* ist die größte Wirtschaft in Vordertupflfing. **Sie** bietet gute deutsche Hausmannskost.

Oft erkennt man diese Firmen daran, dass sie einen Artikel mitführen.

---

Du erwähntest in der Frage:

> Ich bin es gewohnt, über Unternehmen in der dritten Person Plural zu sprechen. Sie sprechen ja auch in der ersten Person Plural über sich selbst.

Nunja, wenn sich ein Unternehmen an die Öffentlichkeit wendet, wer spricht denn da? Üblicherweise ist es nicht die abstrakte Firma, die sich an Außenstehende wendet; es wird vielmehr im Namen aller Mitarbeiter gesprochen. Das ist sinnvoll, denn eine Firma, ein abstraktes Konstrukt, kann nicht sprechen – so wenig wie eine Partei oder ein Verein. Die Mitarbeiter aber können es, und sie sollen auch für die Firma sprechen. Daher der Plural in Eigenverwendung. Gerade bei Parteien hört man ab und an:

> Wir von der Partei deutscher Dummschwafler (PDD) wollen …

Es hat also einen anderen Grund, warum dort der Plural verwendet wird.

Answer (score 0):

Es ist ein *Anglizismus*: die direkte Übertragung einer syntaktischen Konstruktion in eine Sprache, in der sie nicht üblich ist. Wie so viele Anglizismen ist dieser derzeit noch eher falsch; nach der Erfahrung mit vielen anderen Anglizismen ist aber nicht auszuschließen, daß der Gebrauch sich derart verbreitet, daß er irgendwann als richtig gilt.

Comment: Auch im Englischen gibt es Verfechter, das Firmen Singular sind, siehe https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/are-collective-nouns-always-plural-or-are-certain-ones-singular

Comment: Meinst du es ist richtiger im Englischen, wenn von einem Unternehmen gesprochen wird und dann plötzlich der Plural verwendet wird? Ich vermute eher nicht, bin aber nur skeptisch. Ist das so üblich?

Comment: @arved: Danke für den Link, hat sich mit meinem Post überschnitten.

Comment: @Thomas: Ja, zumindest im Britischen Englischen kann man Begriffe, hinter denen eine Mehrzahl an Personen steht, im Plural verwenden: The police _have_ ...(statt: has) usw. Jedenfalls dann, wenn man die Individuen hervorheben will, die hinter der Organisation stecken. (McLaren have won the championships ...)

Comment: "Siemens versprach der Welt eine neue Waschmaschine. Sie stellten sie aber bereits nach weniger als einem Jahr wieder ein." Immer noch ein Anglizismus? Inwiefern?

Comment: @arved, let's call it a Britishism then ;) (I am not sure that that is actually where this comes from, though.)

Answer (score 0):

Aus meinem Sprachgefühl und meiner Spracherfahrung heraus, jedoch ohne es belegen zu können, halte ich die Verwendung des Plurals durchaus für üblich. Bemerkenswert am Beispiel ist, dass in

> Google versprach der Welt einen neuen Messenger.

Singular verwendet wird, in

> Sie stellten ihn aber bereits nach weniger als einem Jahr wieder ein.

hingegen Plural. Aus deskriptiver Perspektive würde ich dafür plädieren, hier einen Wechsel des (grammatischen) **Subjekts** zu konstatieren, während der **Referent** (der Gegenstand in der Welt, auf den Bezug genommen wird, vgl. [Wikipedia:Referent](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referent_(Linguistik))) gleich bleibt. Der Referent wäre beide Male in etwa [Die Leute, die das Unternehmen Google bilden], einmal würde auf ihn mit dem Singular-Wort *Google* referenziert, einmal mit *sie*.

Deswegen denke ich auch, dass es sich hier nicht um einen Anglizismus, nicht um eine der im Englischen üblichen Konstruktion handelt, denn dann müsste es auch im ersten Satz Plural sein

> Google versprachen der Welt einen neuen Messenger.

Für die Frage, ob dieser Wechsel des  **falsch** oder **richtig** ist, ist natürlich entscheidend, welchen Begriff von "richtig" und "falsch" man zugrundelegt. Ich würde es nicht als falsch, wohl aber als stilistische Auffälligkeit bezeichnen; denn der Wechsel des Subjekts und insbesondere des Numerus legt auf den ersten Blick nahe, dass sich auch der Referent geändert hat, sodass hier ein Kohärenzbruch ([Wikipedia:Kohärenz](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koh%C3%A4renz_(Linguistik))) vorliegt, der erst auf Basis der Konversationsmaximen ([Wikipedia:Konversationsmaximen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konversationsmaximen)) "auf den zweiten Blick" gekittet wird.

Diese stilistische Auffälligkeit würde ich vermeiden, wenn ich mich mit Leuten unterhalte, die in der Sprache einen stark normativ geprägten Ansatz vertreten und überdies dazu tendieren, sprachliche Devianz von den (mitunter: vermeintlichen) Normen als Kriterium der Abgrenzung und Bewertung von Menschen verwenden.